# Magento 2 - Install Mirasvit Profiler (Missing symfony/yaml)

Tags: magento2, composer

I am running Magento 2.2.6 and it's a slow instance so I wanted to try out the Mirasvit profiler. However, when I try to enable it, I get an error about yaml not being installed. I dug through the issues on github (https://github.com/mirasvit/module-profiler/issues) and on this issue (https://github.com/mirasvit/module-profiler/issues/36), I found a suggestion of using the dev-master branch of the profiler.

I tried that, and got this:
Problem 1
- Installation request for mirasvit/module-profiler dev-master -> satisfiable by mirasvit/module-profiler[dev-master].
- mirasvit/module-profiler dev-master requires symfony/yaml dev-issue-8145 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[dev-issue-8145] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

If I try to run composer require symfony/yaml, I get symfony/yaml v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v2.8.*]. I tried installing yaml:2.8.49 and got this result:
  Problem 1
    - symfony/yaml v2.8.49 conflicts with symfony/dependency-injection[v3.4.20].
    - symfony/yaml v2.8.49 conflicts with symfony/dependency-injection[v3.4.20].
    - symfony/yaml v2.8.49 conflicts with symfony/dependency-injection[v3.4.20].
    - Installation request for symfony/yaml 2.8.49 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v2.8.49].
    - Installation request for symfony/dependency-injection (locked at v3.4.20) -> satisfiable by symfony/dependency-injection[v3.4.20].

I've cleared the composer cache, run composer update to update existing components and cleared Magento caches and generated files, to no avail.

How do I get this profiler working? Failing that, is there another Magento 2 profiler that I can use that's comparable to Mirasvit?

Comment: In composer.json, the composer/composer version is set strictly. Update it with `^` and try again the composer update.

Comment: Update which component?

Comment: run `composer update`

Comment: I used composer update, unless you mean I need to target a specific module.